# Cannot include jsp in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, web

I need to include .jsp file in my servlet.

I have written simple jsp file, which i have put in dir WEB-INF/jsps/:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<title> Galleries </title>
</head>

<body>
Test
</body>
</html>
```

and servlet:

```
package photoGallery;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GalleriesServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        try 
        {
            System.out.println("Test");
            //get the request dispatcher
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsps/galleries.jsp");
            //forward to the jsp file
            if (dispatcher != null)
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            else 
                System.err.println("Error: dispathcer is null");        
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

in web.xml I have added next lines:

```
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Gallery Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>GalleryServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>photoGallery.GalleriesServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GalleryServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/galleries/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

When I'm openning page

```
http://localhost:8080/PhotoGallery/galleries
```

then in console it prints "Test", but in browser I see "HTTP Status 404 - Not Found"

Where I have made mistake?

Comment: I have tried different pathes like "WEB-INF/jsps/galleries.jsp", "jsps/galleries.jsp" and "/jsps/galleries.jsp" but it doesn't help. I have rebooted computer, eclipse, tomcat result is the same

Comment: Try putting jsps at the same level as WEB-INF and then try to go to the JSP directly.  If that works, then update your getRequestDispatcher() method and you should be good to go.

Comment: what do you mean go to jsp directly?

Comment: I mean type in the path to the JSP in your browser.  You can access it directly if it's not in the WEB-INF

Comment: http://localhost:8080/PhotoGallery/jsps/galleries.jsp (does this work if you don't have the jsps folder under WEB-INF?

Comment: Are you using Tomcat 7 by chance?  I did some researching and it looks like it might not work with the JSPs in WEB-INF with Tomcat 7.

Comment: You could also try getting the servlet context and see if you get a different result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my mistake.
There was other servlet which was mapped to "/*", and because of that appeared errors

Comment: Glad you figured out.  Happy coding.